# Integrating vimeo videos in ios app

Tags: ios, vimeo

In my app I have to integrate the videos available in Vimeo account into my app. so that user can browse the videos and play them, no need to upload the videos. I have already obtained the client key and secret key. can you please help me with the remaining procedure. I have the read the documentation there but dint understand it. the videos I want to retrieve are not public videos. I want to retrieve the videos belong to particular user account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after trying different libraries available.GMOAuth, OAuthConsumer,GTMAuth these are all good libraries for OAuth. But if you want to use OAuth specifically for Vimeo then its  best to use OAuthConsumer, Because its very simple and using that you can go through all the  steps in Vimeo Authentication easily but if you want for twitter or other networks the other libraries are useful.

After you have finished the OAuth steps and obtained OAuthVerifier and token, you have to follow the same method as obtaining the tokens but replacing the url with the method you want to use available at the advanced api methods list. see the Vimeo playground if you want to know about method header and the parameters you have to pass.

Comment: Hi,OAuthConsumer is oauth 1.0 right? Is it working now? Did you tried oauth 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can play the videos via web view

```
 NSMutableString *html = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:1] ;
[html appendString:@"<html><head>"];
[html appendString:@"<style type=\"text/css\">"];
[html appendString:@"body {"];
[html appendString:@"background-color: transparent;"];
[html appendString:@"color: white;"];
[html appendString:@"}"];
[html appendString:@"</style>"];
[html appendString:@"</head><body style=\"margin:0\">"];
[html appendString:@"<iframe src=\"//player.vimeo.com/video/84403700?autoplay=1&amp;loop=1\" width=\"1024\" height=\"768\" frameborder=\"0\" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>"];
[html appendString:@"</body></html>"];


[viewWeb loadHTMLString:html baseURL:urlMovie];
```